# In ubuntu 14.04, grub is slowing down boot up of ubuntu. How to fix it?

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.04

I use only ubuntu. When I first fresh installed ubuntu 14.04, the purple frame hanged there for about 10 seconds. That was too slow for me, since I have i5 and ssd. Before that, I had windows 7, and it booted in seconds. I suspected the purple frame(grub) was slowing it down. So I searched a little bit on google and found [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3j4xmbqO7o) video and did what the guy showed. The purple frame was there for a less time, but it was still there. I changed the **GRUB_TIMEOUT** to 0, so the purple frame shouldn't be there at all(or am I wrong?). I then changed **GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET** to true, updated the grub, restarted the computer, and saw that, although grub timeout was set to 0, it hanged there for about 3 secinds. How to remove it? I don't care about recovery options, I don't need them, since my ubuntu is working great and I backup it regulary. I also tried one program for configuring grub, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to cut down the grub time to about 1s, which is ok for me, by changing the following line(commenting):

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

to

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```